# Changing the array's value through a function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

The function saves the new string and sets it at position 2. But when I run the last "for" there are just some strange symbols.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void edit(int target, char *listf[]){

    char *name[1];

    printf("\nInsert the new name: \n");
    scanf("%s", &name[0]);
    listf[target] = &name[0];

    printf("\nThe information has change!\n");
    printf("Name: %s\n", listf[target]);
    system("pause");   }

int main() {
    char *listf[3] = {"Alpha", "Beta", "Omega"};

    int i;
    int target = 2;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("%s\n", listf[i]);
    }

    edit(target,listf);
    printf(" \n\n");

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        printf("%s\n", listf[i]);
    }

    return 0; }
```

Comment: `scanf("%s", &name[0]);` is a type error. `scanf` `%s` takes a `char *`, but `&name[0]` is a `char **`. Same problem in `listf[target] = &name[0];`.

Comment: @melpomene And how can I solve this problem? I've tried to use cast, but doesn't works.

Comment: What's up with that edit? Why did you break the formatting again?

Comment: @ThiagoBarboza please don't mess up the formatting

Comment: @ThiagoBarboza Why would you cast? Just use the correct format specifier.

Comment: You need to read about *dynamic memory allocation*.  Also the `char *name[1]` is completely meaningless, why just not have `char *name`; also it doesn't point to anywhere at all. Oh, and this shouldn't compile without warnings!

Comment: Compile with -Wall -Wextra and you'll get two warnings from this code.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code. First, the char name is an array of pointers, essentially. And those pointers.......they are not pointing to allocated memory, just garbage data. If you want to make good use of it, you have to assign a pointer to an allocated memory. Now, normally, when you use a function like scanf, they assume that the pointer you given to it(in this case &name[0]) have allocated memory to store the input string. But if you dont do this, your pointer would be pointing to a random address in the memory, possibly editing some other memory cells and causing your program to behave very strangely. So how do you solve this? I'm not claiming my solution to be perfect, but just use a plain char array, preferably a large one, to store the input string. Like this-

```
char name[1000];
```

The second problem is this line-

```
listf[target] = &name[0];
```

The thing here is that the data the name array is pointing to, is temporary. It will only last as long as the function edit() runs. Why? A simple way to say this is that, name belongs to the edit() function. So when edit() terminates, so does everything along with it. Meaning char name wont store whatever you put into it. This is the reason why you were getting strange symbols. So you have to put the contents of the input in another place in the memory. So you'll have to use malloc() here. Here's my fixed version of the edit function-

```
void edit(int target, char *listf[]){


char name[1000];

printf("\nInsert the new name: \n");
scanf("%s", name);

//figure out the length of the string and allocate memory accordingly
int len = strlen(name);
char* new_name = malloc(len * sizeof(char));

printf("Test %d\n", len * sizeof(char));

//copy the contents of name to new_name
strcpy(new_name,name);
listf[target] = new_name;

printf("\nThe information has change!\n");
printf("Name: %s\n", listf[target]);
system("pause");

}
```